# Retrieve the elements prop name and convert as array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I selected the elements `a` by finding it. i would like to make an array by it's names.

I would like to split their name by `-` as well. i tried this way, but i am getting wrong result..

what would be the correct way here:

```js
var name = $('a');


var names = name.map(function () {
    return $(this).prop('name');
});

 console.log(names.split('-')); // not getting result. getting error
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#" id="one" name="one" >ONe</a>
    <a href="#" id="two" name="two" >ONe</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't use .split() on an array; strings only.

Comment: Do you want to split *each* name by hyphens? If so, what should the result look like? Assuming I have `onename` and `two-name`, should I get `["onename", "two", "name"]` or `["onename", ["two", "name"]]` or `[["onename"], ["two", "name"]]`?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you'd like to see get logged in that snippet? As an aside, you should be using `$.fn.attr` to get the name, not `.prop`.

Comment: @JAAulde, can you tell me how to use the `$.fn.attr` please, it looks it may fit for my requirement. Basically i would like to send the array to backend as `['one-two]`  and etc.

Comment: @3gwebtrain it is used in the same manner as, and returns similarly to, `$.fn.prop` but is used for element attributes as opposed to DOM object properties. The difference is subtle, but `name` attributes fall into the former. Example: `$(this).attr('name')`. Note, this is all an aside and will not solve the primary issue you're questioning. My original question still stands, what _is_ your expected result?

Comment: see, my comments, I would like to collect the both of `a` elements name and put in to an array, and need to send back to server. for server end requesting to add `-` in between the names.

Comment: @3gwebtrain So you want to ***join*** the elements of the array, not split them, correct?

Comment: yes. you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the clarifications in your comments, the following is how you would use jQuery and its `map` functionality to collect a set of `name` attributes from a collection of `A` elements and join them with the `-` character:

```
$(function () {
    var links = $('a'),
        // names will  be a jQuery collection because we're using `$.fn.map`
        names = links.map(function () {
            // using `.attr` instead of `.prop`
            return $(this).attr('name');
        });

    // Because `names` is a jQuery collection, before we `join` them
    // we have to get the array out of the collection using `get`
    console.log(names.get().join('-'));
});
```

**[Demo on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I5fNF2rXauyvi4OFVcsM?p=preview)**

Answer (score -1):

The variable `names`already is an object of these 2 values.

You can log theme using these commands.

```
console.log(names[0]);
console.log(names[1]);
```